# How to use a very large Forstner-style bit

Tags: drilling, drill-bits

This Forstner bit is 92mm in diameter, it's very large. I need to make a clean hole into a block of wood.

Looks a bit dangerous, or looks like there's a risk to break the bit or tool.

So how am I supposed to use it, with a hand drill, with a drill press, and at what rpm ?

Common sense tells me to use the drill press, because the hole would be straight, but reading the bit's Amazon reviews people say that it's more dangerous than with a hand drill!

Here's what the bit looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at some of the previous Qs that include the word Forstner (both Comments and Answers) for the general advice on them & especially on larger-diameter ones. I do want to point out that this **isn't** a Forstner bit though, it's derived from them but all the key details that are changed here make it a different bit entirely.... most especially the lead screw. Lead screws can be a real nightmare for power drilling and I've had some minor accidents myself. Because you HAVE TO step down speed with this bit already (due to the diameter) that may be much less of an issue than it often is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not to be overly picky but I think it's important to point out that *this is not a Forstner bit*, no matter how it's named by the manufacturer. It's clearly derived from them of course, but all the key details that are changed here make it a different bit entirely..... most especially the lead screw.

---

Depending on the wood species you're drilling into, the thickness of the stock, the number of holes and how a couple of test drills go I'd be very tempted to do this with a brace myself if the lead screw is not removable. Lead screws already take the place of some/a lot of the downwards pressure requirement when drilling, which is why they're a feature of nearly all later bits designed for braces.

However, that said this bit is obviously intended for use with a power drill and >99% of users are going to use them that way. And the lead screw I think changes the best-practice advice from what it normally is for Forstner bits and derivative designs (which is that once you go above a certain diameter you should always mount them in a drill press/bench drill).

Lead screws can be a real nightmare for power drilling and I've had some minor accidents myself (despite thinking I was being careful enough). And there's lots of long-standing advice from the old days to never use a bit with a lead screw in a drill press because the self-feeding is at odds with the way the drill press wants to advance.

**Note:** one portion of standing advice for large bits like this should remain, and that is they should be run *much* more slowly than smaller ones (because the speed *at the rim* must be controlled to avoid overheating). Here this will also help reduce the risk of runaway feeding.

- Adjust drill to a very slow speed, and here even more than normally try to let the bit do the work.
- *Be prepared to stop if something goes wrong.*
- Make sure the workpiece is clamped down **very** securely.
- If drilling multiple holes and the rim is getting uncomfortably hot put the drill aside to allow the bit to cool before proceeding (or dunk in water).

Comment: +100 for secure clamping! If you're using a drill press and going slowly, the lead screw might grab the wood and pull it up since you're driving the bit down slowly.

Comment: The screw is removable. And I got an extra screw with the package  (and allen key), not sure why. should I remove the screw? Centering the hole should not be a problem. I could just put a mark with a pen

Comment: From the image it looked like it might be removable but I didn't want to assume. This is a good feature and adds to the utility of the bit, since one can choose to use it either way for different circumstances. Regardless though, as @AloysiusDefenestrate points out in his Comment the centre of the proposed circle could be drilled out so there's nothing for the screw to bite into. This is particularly practical if using a drill press/bench drill since the two bits used in sequence are automatically aligned assuming the workpiece doesn't move (or can be put back in the same place using stops).

Comment: *"And I got an extra screw with the package (and allen key), not sure why."* Lead screws are notorious for becoming damaged accidentally so that may be the main reason. But also with the fairly fine pitch the threading could jam up easily from wood and/or adhesive residues (e.g. from ply or MDF). Even if just from sticky hot wood dust sometimes this gunk is nearly impossible to remove without the right solvent available — pure mechanical means, like brushing with a fine wire brush, are often not enough..... unless one wants to meticulously pick it out with a needle tip (been there, done that!)

Comment: I made a test hole and it was surprisingly smooth and clean - https://i.imgur.com/9qmACqU.png couldn't remove the screw tho. seems to be stuck there

Comment: That is not too shabby at all! Even the bottom of the hole is way better than I expected. Impressed! About the lead screw, might be (and probably *should* be) a tight fit — at least a machinists' "sliding fit" if not tighter — requiring it to pulled with pliers, suitably cushioned to prevent damage to the thread obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Well in general I always recommend using a drill press with forsner bits, they aren't required, but you got to take a lot of care if you don't and the press you get a cleaner hole more often.  In either case for one that size the piece you are drilling should be clamped down pretty well, since the first danger is the piece spinning and getting you.

the next thing is it is best to have a drill with the side handle (if you are using a hand drill, or you have a good chance of hurting yourself when the bit catches.

And since this is one with the center bit being a screw, that just adds to the fun, since it just keeps pulling the bit into the wood, and if you have an under powered drill (hand or press) it can make it 10 times harder to do, since you will then need to go slow enough that the screw is just drilling and not pulling...

Comment: You can always drill out the center hole to stop the lead screw from pulling. (Which will help with the ‘clean’ part of your wishlist, though quite honestly, that’s not a bit likely to produce a clean hole. Maybe clamp some sacrificial plywood to reduce tearout.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate that is also a good idea!